# ASP Application on IIS crash

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net

ASP application always hangs and didn't work on IIS during rush hours connections

Also other scripts like PHP are working properly on IIS. The problem only with ASP.

I'm receiving this error when i'm trying to open the ASP script.

```
================================================================
Server Error in '/' Application.

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +404
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +412
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +1363
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData() +58
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +118
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6312385
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +6313986
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +538
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +28
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +256
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +19
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +968
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +207
   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +500
   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +50
   System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +383
   website.Controls.Homepage.website_Column.BindData() +2671
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +190
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3048

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The application is timing out while trying to connect to the database. You can either

1. Extend the timeout parameter on the database connection.
2. Fix your database so it can handle the load you're throwing at it. Also, do some capacity management.

Comment: I'm a windows beginner, How can i extend the timeout on the db connection .? and How can i disable the timeout so it didn't loose the connection.

Comment: You adjust the `ConnectionTimeout` property on the `SqlConnection` object in your code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx). But the default is 30 seconds, so if it's taking longer than 30s to even connect to your database, you've got database problems. Disabling the timeout is, I believe, impossible. At some point, synchronous tasks have to timeout, otherwise they'll just wait forever.